# Passport and facebook - get account creation date

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

I'm using Express and Passport with the Facebook strategy and I need to get the creation date of the account, I have serached around but I haven't been able to find anything, some say it was possible but not any longer.

So, does anyone know if it's possible and if yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Of the Facebook user account? No, that's not available.

Comment: Yes, of the Facebook user account. So there isn't any way at all to get the creation date of a Facebook user account? Why would Facebook ever hide that?

Comment: Why would you ever need that, and why don't you think privacy is more important?